# What is/was lingerd? How it exactly worked?

Tags: apache-http-server, tcpip

I checked one very old Apache/PHP presentation. Presentation was outdated, but most of the things were very good.

On one of the slides they mentioned `lingerd` - "properly close connections bla bla".

Since original `lingerd` website no longer seems to exist, I have following questions:

1. What was the problem `lingerd` used to solve?
2. How it did it? It is Apache module or something else?
3. Depending of first two answers - is this problem still exists on Linux and who is handling it now - kernel or Apache webserver?

Answer (score 0):

#### The original lingerd website no longer seems to exist,

You can find the lingerd website in the [Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20160531062129/http://www.iagora.com:80/about/software/lingerd/)

---

#### What was the problem lingerd used to solve? It is Apache module or something else?

> Lingerd is a daemon (service) designed to take over the job of
>   properly closing network connections from an http server like Apache.
>
> Because of some technical complications in the way TCP/IP and HTTP
>   work, each Apache process currently wastes a lot of time "lingering"
>   on client connections, after the page has been generated and sent.
>   Lingerd takes over this job, leaving the Apache process immediately
>   free to handle a new connection. As a result, Lingerd makes it
>   possible to serve the same load using considerably fewer Apache
>   processes. This translates into a reduced load on the server.
>
> Lingerd is particularily useful in Apache webservers that generate
>   dynamic pages (e.g in conjunction with mod_perl, mod_php or
>   Java/Jakarta/Tomcat).
>
> More importantely, lingerd can only do an effective job if HTTP
>   Keep-Alives are turned off; since keep-alives are useful for images,
>   the recommended lingerd setup is to have an
>   Apache/mod_whatever/lingerd server for the dynamic pages, and a plain
>   Apache (or thttpd or boa) for the images.

Source [WHAT IS LINGERD?](https://web.archive.org/web/20160731120950/http://www.iagora.com/about/software/lingerd/README.txt)

Comment: "each Apache process currently wastes a lot of time "lingering" on client connections" - was that apache-related issue? is it fixed now?

Comment: @Nick Not sure. I guess it is due to socket close timeouts. Outside my area of detailed knowledge.